# Accessing ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, ssh

**Scenario**

I have 2 machines(running OS Windows 10) which are connected to same network named as MachineA and MachineB. I have enabled Hyper-V on MachineA and installed one ubuntu server and assigned default network in Hyper-V. i can access the ubuntu server from MachineA (ssh) but not from MachineB. below are the internal ip's of it.

i can rdp MachineA from MachineB. i have disabled firewall in both MachineA and MachineB.

MachineA (Windows 10) - 172.16.1.56

Machineb (Windows 10) - 172.16.1.72

Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) - 172.19.205.94

**Issue:**

when i tried to access Ubuntu server from MachineB, i am getting below exception

*ssh_exchange_identification: read: connection reset*

Please suggest.

Comment: This is probably not related to the virtual Ubuntu Linux system but to the network configuration of the virtualization and/or the firewall configuration of the Windows host. Please also show the network mask on all machines.

Comment: Do you have some sort of route between the Windows systems and the Ubuntu Server?  They are in completely different subnets so without a route they cannot see each other.  I use the [Online Subnet Calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/) to make sure my network for local is correct.